# log4net debug appender not working in VS2017 Community

Tags: c#, log4net

I've had an application with log4net working for years.  Now, the debug appender that used to work is no longer working.  I've recently upgraded to 2017 visual studio community.  Don't know if this is related.

Here is the config to double check.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<log4net>

<root>
    <level value="Debug" />
    <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
    <appender-ref ref="DebugAppender" />

</root>

<appender name="DebugAppender" type="log4net.Appender.DebugAppender">
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="[%thread] %-5level %message%newline"/>
    </layout>
</appender>
    <appender name="TraceAppender" type="log4net.Appender.TraceAppender">
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline%exception"/>
       </layout>
  </appender>

   <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="${ApplicationRollingLogFile}" />       
    <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock"/>
    <appendToFile value="false" />

    <rollingStyle value="Size" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="20" />
    <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="~%logger|%thread|%-5level |%message |%date{s} |%newline"/>
    </layout>
</appender>

    <appender name="GlobalExceptionLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <file value="${GlobalExceptionLogFile}" />
        <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock"/>
        <appendToFile value="true" />

        <rollingStyle value="Size" />
        <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
        <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="~%logger|%thread|%-5level |%message |%date{s} |%newline"/>
       </layout>
  </appender> 





<!-- ===================================================================-->
<!-- General Loggers -->
<!-- ===================================================================-->

<!--by default, make all loggers INFO-->
<logger name="Common.NonVisual">
<level value="Info"/>
</logger>

<logger name="Common.Visuals">
<level value="Info"/>
</logger>

<logger name="Common.Visuals.Zooming">
<level value="Info"/>
</logger>

<logger name="UnitTests">
<level value="Debug"/>
</logger>

<logger name="Common.NonVisual.IoC">
<level value="Debug"/>
</logger>

 <!--don't want to see much of the spring logging statements-->
<logger name="Spring">
<level value="Info"/>
</logger>

<logger name="Tower.AppGui.PSwipe">
<level value="Info"/>
</logger>

<logger name="Tower.Services.SystemMonitorService">
<level value="Info"/>
</logger>

<logger name="Heartbeat">
<level value="Debug"/>
</logger>

<logger name="Common.Wpf.Visuals.ScreenSaver">
<level value="Info"/>
</logger>

<logger name="Common.Wpf.Visuals.ScreenSaverCanvas">
<level value="Info"/>
</logger>


<logger name="Tower.Services.ValveController.Drivers">
<level value="Debug"/>
</logger>

<logger name="Tower.Services.DisplayWatcher">
<level value="Info"/>
</logger>

<logger name="Tower.AppCommon.util.DbUtil">
<level value="Info"/>
</logger>

<logger name="Tower.AppCommon.Models.ButtonModel">
<level value="Info"/>
</logger>

<logger name="Tower.Services.Motherboard.MotherboardControllerService">
<level value="Info"/>
</logger>

<logger name="Common.Wpf.Visuals.Util.GlobalExceptionHandler">
<level value="Debug"/>
<appender-ref ref="GlobalExceptionLogFileAppender" />
</logger>

<logger name="Tower.Services.Rcm">
<level value="Debug"/>
</logger>

<logger name="Common.Wpf.Visuals">
<level value="Info"/>
</logger>

<logger name="Tower.AppGui.OneButtonPseudoDialogViewModel">
<level value="Info"/>
</logger>

<logger name="Tower.Services.PDM.ProductDataService">
<level value="Info"/>
</logger>

<logger name="Common.NonVisual.SettingsManager">
<level value="Info"/>
</logger>

<logger name="Tower.Services.Web">
<level value="Debug"/>
</logger>
</log4net>
```

Comment: Can you please show a [mcve]? Along with code?

Comment: You got no `DebugLogger`defined, maybe thats the problem?

Comment: @pulle - at the root node the use of "DebugAppender" is defined.  The next node is the definition of the DebugAppender. So it is defined.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... my mistake. right click and turn on program output.  I usually turn these all of except for program output.  I guess I got in a hurry and turned everything off.

Comment: Sounds pretty stupid, but it took me some time to figure it out as well.